# Add Custom Text on Timepicker of Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I'm working on availability for worker page in my project and I'm using kendo UI timepicker, 
I want to add a text called “anytime” for start time and end time.. 
if its possible, how can I make it? thanks.